# Handling academia politics - an early career case

Tags: application, job-search, job, faculty-application, politics

This question is based mostly not on relevant personal experiences, but is largely inspired by reading here and there mentioning of the politics aspect in academia. At the present time, I am interested in this subject from *practical perspective* - as a recent Ph.D. graduate, looking for a postdoctoral or junior faculty position. In particular, I'm concerned about the following aspects:

- Should I care about this issue at this point of my career? (Next questions are based on *Yes*)
- How should I assess the political situation in a department or lab of potential employment? (Here I imply both online assessment and on-site, should I be invited for interviews.)
- What strategy and specific steps should I take, based on the assessment results?
- What are political differences, if any, between postdoctoral and junior faculty positions? How should they impact my strategy and what steps should be taken, based on position type?

Comment: This question was closed as "too broad" and the OP has divided it into several separate questions. I have merged the answer given here into the most relevant of those separate questions.